# Negative impact of setting sql query command timeout to max

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I came across a timeout exception during the execution of my sql query. So i increased the timeout in my C# code and now its working fine.

```
DbCommand.CommandTimeout = 3600;
```

This must have been occurred as a result of increasing data in the database. 
I do not want this exception to occur in the future for any other scenarios.

1. So is it a good practice to add the command timeout line in all my methods?
2. It would be great to know the positive and negative side of this operation.

Comment: It depends on what you are doing really, but as a general rule my first action would not be to increase the timeout, but to look at why the query is taking longer, and what can be done to improve the performance. Only once you are happy that your query is then fully optimised to run as fast as possible should you consider extending the timeout. With a timeout of 2 hours I really hope you are calling the query asynchronously?

Comment: @GarethD Not all the queries are taking this long. This one deals with hell lot of data. In parallel the optimizing work is going on too. But my question is, is it ok to increase timeout for all the methods( they dont need it for now, in future they may need more time for large data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Having a reasonable expectation of how fast you expect something to run is always a good idea, but frankly it is very rarely necessary to specify an explicit timeout - usually this is only done when you *know* something will take a long time and you can't currently fix it at the db for whatever reasons. It is the exception, not the norm. If you have utility code that wraps your data access, you could perhaps provide a centralized default timeout
2. The only positive aspect of setting a long timeout is as a band-aid: to make it work. However, this is an automatic code smell - you should really be looking at *why* it is taking so long, and re-architect it a bit. There are significant real issues that this can raise, including long running **blocked** operations (perhaps even an undetectable deadlock) that will **never** finish; the other more immediate negative aspect is that it *distracts you from fixing the real problem*

Comment: Thanks for the great answer(+1). But i have queries that deals with really huge data. So do you think that fixing the query is the only solution ? I agree that query can be optimized(doing it in parallel). But still when the data grows larger so is the time of execution right ?

Comment: @Ebenezar well, first I'd look at just about every other alternative ;p

Answer (score 0):

you also set time out in SQL Database Side

Simply you add following code in your Stored Procedure OR Query

```
        EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'remote query timeout', 1800
        reconfigure
        EXEC sp_configure
```

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that ADO.NET also specifies a timeout, and has an inbuilt default - 15 seconds, IIRC. As such, this is unlikely to do much for ADO.NET connections

Comment: @MarcGravell FYI for all: the default value of the Timeout property on an IDbCommand object is 30 seconds, not 15 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx